# Javascript Electron app: Which directories should be saved in git repository

Tags: angular, git, electron

When an Electron app is created in node.js (with the CLI), a lot of directories and files are created in the project directory, but a lot of these files are auto-generated and I don't see the point to save them in my git repository.

What is usually done in this case ? Which directories must be absolutely saved ? Is there a simple way to recover all these generated files without having them in my git repo ?

Answer (score 1):

In your project directory, Node usually install some dependencies that are saved in a new directory created the moment you run `npm install`, these are files you need when running the app, but for you to push your work to git, you will need to create a new file with the name `.gitignore`. In this file you can include all the names of the directory and files you will not want git to include when you run `git add .`, and this should include your `node_modules` which is where the auto-generated files are.

Which means that when you push the work to git, whenever you will want to `git clone` the repo, you will have to run `npm install` again to install all the dependencies.

I hope this helps.